# get error for facebook login "the operation cannot be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)" for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, iphone-5

I created an application using facebook sdk 3.1.1 but i get error like "the operation cannot be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)" for iPhone 5. my bundle id and app id are correct. So can any one has any idea?

Thank you

Comment: this error occurd sometime or continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set sandbox mode to Off in your application settings in facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Later i found that my native ios login had failed. I deleted that account and it worked fine.